# Focus on search text field and making search list navigable

Tags: javascript, user-interface, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, unobtrusive-javascript

I've a search feature in one of code which ideally performs a search on the list of values (small number).

```
<li>abc</li> 
<li>def</li> 
...
```

I've a search button in the bottom, I put a `keyup` event listener to get instant searches. Now the question is how can I make it navigable.
Ideal scenario search for some text, hit enter and it should open the first element, else you should be able to navigate through.

If I'm not clear above I'm actually asking for a feature very similar to Facebook Chat sidebar search.

Comment: Please show the necessary information: 1. Where is this feature located (eg: options page)? 2. What is the *real structure* of your HTML.

Comment: Indeed. Can you also post what you've already written? It's not clear if you have the basic search filtering functionality working or not. Additionally, what do you mean by "navigable"? Do you mean that you should be able to click/keyboard through the results, or something else?

Comment: @RobW 1: Its on the popup.html 2:its very plain li elements in a div.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 Sorry if i'm not clear, basically what i need is navigatable list first. Then i need to focus stay on search box while list is still navigable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of the OP who has not added jQuery to the list of tags ( I congratulate you ), I'll add a small navigation plugin in pure JavaScript.

**Disclosure - the credit for the actual logic would go to Eric Priestley of Facebook fame as this was lifted from his Javelin JS library.**

I'm posting a link to the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/55R39/30/). I also assume from your question that you already have a *search* solution in place and are simply looking for a navigation solution.

Cross posting from fiddle. I've commented a lot in the code, so should be self explanatory. Though if you do have doubts, get in touch.

**HTML**
Can be anything you desire. For brevity, I've added this

```
<input id='control' type='text' placeholder='Search text here' />
<!-- List of results - hardcoded for now -->
<ul id='hardpoint' class='hidden'>
    <li class='item'>Search item 1</li>
    <li class='item'>Search item 2</li>
    <li class='item'>Search item 3</li>
    <li class='item'>Search item 4</li>
</ul>​
```

**The code**

```
(function() {


    /**
     * Helper functions
     */
    var bind = function( context, func, more ){
        if (typeof func !== 'function') {
            throw new Error ("No function supplied to bind function");
        }
        var bound = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments ).slice(2);
        if (func.bind) {
            return func.bind.apply(func, [context].concat(bound));
        }
        return function() {
            return func.apply(context || window, bound.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments )));
        }
    };

    var getChildElements = function(node) {
        var childNodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(node.childNodes);
        childNodes = childNodes.filter(function(item) {
            return item.tagName && item.nodeType && item.nodeType === 1 && item !== node;
        });
        return childNodes;
    };

    var hasClass = function(node, className) {
        return ((' ' + node.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') > -1);
    };

    var alterClass = function(node, className, add) {
        var has = hasClass(node, className);
        if (add && !has) {
            node.className = node.className.trim() + ' ' + className;
        }
        else if (has && !add) {
            node.className = node.className.replace(
            new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + className + '(?:\\s|$)', 'g'), ' ');
        }
    };

    var getIndex = function( list, element ){
        var index = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if( list[i] === element ){
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        };
        return index;
    };


    // Start of plugin
    // Constructor
    var ListNavigator = function(config) {};

    // This can be moved within constructor if you so prefer
    ListNavigator.prototype.init = function(config) {
        // On what element do you want the controls to activate
        // Pressing up down etc on this element, triggers tha navigation
        this.control = document.getElementById(config.control);

        // The list of results that can be navigated
        this.hardpoint = document.getElementById(config.hardpoint);

        // A list of items ( usually, childNodes ) of hardpoint
        // Dynamically populated
        this.display =  getChildElements(this.hardpoint);;

        // What to set the focus on initially
        this.focus = -1;

        // Specify a function to execute when the user chooses a result
        // Keydown - Return : configured to be the choose event type now
        this.choose = config.choose;

        this.selector = config.selector;
    };

    ListNavigator.prototype.run = function() {
        var controlEvents = ['focus', 'blur', 'keydown', 'input'],
            mouseEvents = [ 'mouseover', 'mouseout', 'mousedown' ],
            self = this,
            selector = this.selector;

        controlEvents.forEach(function(event) {
            self.control.addEventListener(event, bind(self, self.handleEvent), false);
        });

        mouseEvents.forEach(function(event) {
            self.hardpoint.addEventListener(event, bind(self, self.onmouse), true);
        });
    };

    // Logic to change the focus on keydown
    ListNavigator.prototype.changeFocus = function(d) {
        var n = Math.min( Math.max( -1, this.focus + d ), this.display.length - 1);

        if (this.focus >= 0 && this.focus < this.display.length) {
            alterClass(this.display[this.focus], 'focused', false);
        }

        this.focus = n;
        this.drawFocus();
        return true;
    };

    // Set the focus on the targetted element
    ListNavigator.prototype.drawFocus = function() {
        var f = this.display[this.focus];
        if (f) {
            alterClass(f, 'focused', true);
        }
    };

    // Handle mouse events
    ListNavigator.prototype.onmouse = function(event) {
        var target = event.target, type = event.type;
        if ( hasClass( target, this.selector ) ) {
            if ( type === 'mousedown' ) {
                // Choose this element
                this.choose(target);
            }
            else if ( type === 'mouseover' ) {
                // Set the focus to element on which mouse is hovering on
                this.focus = getIndex( this.display, target );
                this.drawFocus();
            } 
            else if ( type === 'mouseout' ){
                // Reset the display to none
                this.changeFocus(Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
            }
        };
    };

    ListNavigator.prototype.handleEvent = function(e) {
        var type = e.type;
        if (type === 'blur') {
            this.focused = false;
            this.hide();
        } else {
            alterClass(this.hardpoint, 'hidden', false);
            this.update(e);
        }
    };

    ListNavigator.prototype.hide = function() {
        this.changeFocus(Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
        this.display = [];
        alterClass(this.hardpoint, 'hidden', true);
    };

    ListNavigator.prototype.submit = function() {
        if (this.focus >= 0 && this.display[this.focus]) {
            this.choose(this.display[this.focus]);
        } else {

            if (this.display.length) {
                this.changeFocus(1);
                this.choose(this.display[this.focus]);
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

    ListNavigator.prototype.update = function(event) {

        console.log( 'upadte' );
        this.display = getChildElements(this.hardpoint);

        if (event.type === 'focus') {
            this.focused = true;
        }

        var k = event.which;
        if (k && event.type == 'keydown') {
            switch (k) {
            case 38:
                if (this.display.length && this.changeFocus(-1)) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
                break;
            case 40:
                if (this.display.length && this.changeFocus(1)) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
                break;
            case 13:
                if (this.display.length) {
                    this.hide();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    this.submit();
                }
                break;
            case 27:
                if (this.display.length) {
                    this.hide();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
                break;
            case 9:
                // If the user tabs out of the field, don't refresh.
                return;
            }
        }

    };

    window.ListNav = ListNavigator

})();

var nav = new ListNav();
nav.init({
    control: 'control',
    hardpoint: 'hardpoint',
    selector: 'item',
    choose: function(){
        console.log( arguments );
    }
});
nav.run();​
```

Answer (score 0):

If this was my page I would have the searchable elements tagged with a class such as `<li class="searchable">abc</li>` and I would use jQuery to find all searchable elements in my page via a selector such as `$("li.searchable:contains('" + SEARCHTERM + "')")` where earlier we defined var SEARCHTERM = $("#searchbox").text();

There are some fine tunings that you may want to do with this (:contains is case sensitive for example), but does this sound like it's in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for autocomplete functionality...? If so you should look into the jQuery UI autocomplete: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="html">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Search Users</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#searched_users_list").hide();
    $("#search_user").keyup(function(){
        var what_to_search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        if(what_to_search != ''){
            $("#users_list").hide();
            $("#searched_users_list").show();
        }else{
            $("#users_list").show();
            $("#searched_users_list").hide();
        }
        var searched_users = '';
        var user_name = '';
        $("#users_list").children('li:contains("'+what_to_search+'")').each(function(){
            user_name = $(this).html();
            searched_users += "<li>"+user_name+"</li>";
        });

        if(searched_users != '')
            $("#searched_users_list").html(searched_users);
        else
            $("#searched_users_list").html('<li>No user found....</li>');
    })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="users_list">
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>defa</li>
    <li>ghife</li>
</ul>
<ul id="searched_users_list">
    <li>No user found....</li>
</ul>
<input type="text" name="search_users" id="search_user" value="" />
</body>
</html>

It's my first post... Sorry If something is odd.
```

Comment: Please check this. I hope this will help.

Comment: This is a complete working example like FB chat search... Try it out :)

Comment: looks like this is more of only a search feature which i already have, what i was looking for is Navigation through the list and first answer solves look at the jsfiddle.